# appending three CSV files

Tags: linux, awk, sed, csv-simple

I have three CSV files which have the same same row count.

```
1.csv
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9

2.csv
4
5
6

3.csv
8
9
10
```

After combining I want the result as

```
result.csv
1,2,3,4,8
4,5,6,5,9
7,8,9,6,10
```

So I tried with

```
paste 1.csv 2.csv | tr "\t" "," > intermediate.csv
paste intermediate.csv 3.csv | tr "\t" "," > result.csv
```

But I got result like

```
 result.csv
    1,2,3, 4,8
    4,5,6, 5,9
    7,8,9, 6,10
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
paste -d, 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv > result.csv
```

The `-d` flag sets the delimiter so you don't have to attempt to clobber the tabs with `tr`.